# Is TESS a sky-survey? Is the tag sufficiently broad for all kinds of surveys?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, specific-tag

The [sky-survey](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sky-survey) tag currently has 21 questions after I added it to [Any plans for TESS after it finishes northern sky survey?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32801/7982)

For background, Wikipedia's [Astronomical survey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_survey) says

> An astronomical survey is a general map or image of a region of the sky **which lacks a specific observational target**. Alternatively, an astronomical survey may comprise a set of many images or spectra of objects which share a common type or feature. Surveys are often restricted to one band of the electromagnetic spectrum due to instrumental limitations, although multiwavelength surveys can be made by using multiple detectors, each sensitive to a different bandwidth

I just want to double check if `sky-survey` is a sufficiently general term to apply to all types of surveys. TESS is an exoplanet survey and does indeed look for *specific things* though it doesn't *a priori* look at specific targets.

---

**also note:** "There is no usage guidance for this tag … yet!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `sky-survey` is totally fine. Among astronomers, these are normally just called "surveys" because the "sky" part is implied by context and the background of the people having  the discussion. For the more general audience of SE, putting the "sky-" prefix before it helps remove any ambiguity about what is being surveyed (and would be in good company of probably **the** most impactful sky survey SDSS - the *Sloan Digital Sky Survey*). As for TESS, 'Survey' is in its acronym...

Comment: This works for me, thanks! I've written a short definition, feel free to edit further. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tags/sky-survey/info